# RegEx - get only last asterisk

Tags: regex, xregexp

Is it possible to do a RegEx to only match the last asterisk right before and first asterisk right after an value?

Value: `**example**`

My actual regex: `/\*(.*?)\*/g`

My actual regex matches the two asterisks before and after word example, but i want to do a regex that only matches the last asterisk right before and the first asterisk right after the word.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `/[*][^*]+[*]/gm`

Works as tested on regex101.com

Comment: Im sorry for not explaining properly the question, the value: **(double asterisk)example(double asterisk)** could be any value not only A-Z, could be even with numbers or special characters, like: **(double asterisk)123-EXAMPLE:(double asterisk)**, is it possible to do it?

Comment: @esteves67 see my updated answer